# Error with Xcode Swift 3: Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' and found this candidate (Swift.MutableIndexable)

Tags: ios, swift, segue

My code is :

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

  let playerViewController = segue.destination as! PlayerViewController
  playerViewController.ID = channelsDataArray[selectedVideoIndex]["ID"] 
                            as? [String: AnyObject]

}
```

at line:

```
playerViewController.ID = channelsDataArray[selectedVideoIndex]["ID"] 
                          as? [String: AnyObject]
```

Error is :

> found this candidate(swift.MutableIndexable)
>   found this candidate(swift.array)
>   found this candidate(swift.indexable)

Comment: what is the data type of ID in PlayerViewController

Comment: Data type of ID is String

Comment: Probably `channelsDataArray` is something *typeless* like a Foundation array and if `ID` is String the cast will always fail

Comment: This is the type of channelDataArray `var channelsDataArray: Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>> = []`

Comment: In Swift 3 replace `AnyObject` with `Any` unless you need explicitly `AnyObject`. The most unspecified dictionary in Swift 3 is `[AnyHashable:Any]` but if all keys are `String` use `[String:Any]` and if the values are more specific than `Any` use also the more specific type. That helps the compiler dramatically

Comment: how can type that code

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: how can i fix this error . please help me

Comment: Did you try my suggestions?

Comment: i couldn't Understand . can you help me this by doing code ?

Comment: Instead `Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>` use `Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>` and replace all other occurrences of `AnyObject` also with `Any`